# sum the elements of 2 NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda3

```
import numpy as np
n1=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
n2=np.array([50,60,70,80])

np.sum([n1,n2])
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d22debd88ae6> in <module>
      3 n2=np.array([50,60,70,80])
      4 
----> 5 np.sum([n1,n2])

<__array_function__ internals> in sum(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
   2239         return res
   2240 
-> 2241     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
   2242                           initial=initial, where=where)
   2243 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     85                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     86 
---> 87     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     88 
     89 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (4,)
```

I am trying the sum the elements of these arrays.....but it is throwing this error in jupiter notebook

Comment: What do you expect to get? Sum of all the numbers in both arrays? Then `n1.sum() + n2.sum()`.

Comment: When asking for a question, please remember to also mention the expected outcome as @YevhenKuzmovych mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
np.sum(np.append(n1,n2))
```

You first need to append the two arrays together, then you can take the total sum.